# Can a custom xcode template partially and selectively enable ARC (Automatic Reference Counting)?

Tags: objective-c, shell, plist, xcode4.2, automatic-ref-counting

Problem: A library I use won't support ARC (Automatic Reference Counting).

Background (for those unfamiliar to ARC): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html

Manual Solution: Add the -fno-objc-arc option for each implementation file of the library, and otherwise use ARC normally in my application code.

Observation: The following template file can be copied and most likely be used to either turn ARC completely ON or OFF (without adding the compiler flags above -- the in-between solution that I need):

"/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/Project Templates/iOS Reference Counting.xctemplate"

Question Restatement: Is there a way to avoid the manual solution?  (Copy and Pasting in the -fno-objc-arc option over 100 times is inconvenient.  I hope Apple exposes a programmatic solution.  I would not want to use Automator.app to do the copy/pasting since the Xcode UI will very likely change.)

Example Xcode4 template Generator: https://github.com/MrGando/Xcode-4-Template-Generator/blob/master/template_generator.py

Note template_generator.py has experimental Shared Build Settings.  I want selectively shared (partially shared) settings.  In addition it would be desirable to change the NSAutoreleasePool in main() to an @autorelease block, either with a macro substitution, or by providing a 2nd main.m file.

Comment: Yes, and I have moved on with that solution for my own project; however, it would be useful to have the template wizard let the programmer choose whether or not to enable ARC, with minimal bother about "legacy" non-ARC code, and existing boilerplate in the template code itself.

Comment: You all made good comments.  I have found in practice, since GCC does not support the -fno-objc-arc option (only the Apple-LLVM/clang compiler does), that ARC migration will probably continue to be a manual process, and the templates may take a while to catch up.  I have migrated to ARC successfully on more than one project, and it's not so hard.  It's on my XCode Refactoring Tool Wishlist.  A higher moderator may close this question unless someone wants to add an exhaustive howto.

Answer (score 3):

no, but you're doing it the hard way... simply create a static library target for these MRC sources (if one does not already exist -- it is a 3rd party library), then set the appropriate build settings per target. then link the library with your final executable.

Comment: Two questions:
A) Wouldn't I have to reformulate the static target every time the library changes (which may be often)?
B) Would I still have to add -fno-objc-arc for each file within that target, or could the option apply to all?  The referenced Transitioning to ARC Release Notes don't mention this configuration; they only state that the option must be specified for each file individually.

Comment: If you can provide an example howto/tutorial (or link to one) and it truly simplifies the process of turning ARC on or off, I'll give you (or the first answerer:-) the ANSWERED symbol of approval(!)

Comment: @mda a) you just configure the target as the library that you link to - then all clients/apps that use it link to that. they would refer to the same target. there is no reformulation (but somebody would need to add all the sources to compile). the library you use may already provide this static library/project for your convenience. b) no. you just set the flag at the target level for this library which uses MRC. the sources will inherit the settings, unless there is a build setting overridden at a level which dominates, or if you have passed conflicting flags to the compiler.

Comment: I need to support GCC also, and it throws an error when encountering -fno-objc-arc

Comment: @mda you don't even need to enable ARC when doing what i've outlined. iow, there's nothing to *disable*.

Comment: i feel like i am completely distilling and repeating what i have said: 1) create a static library for the MRC files 2) turn off the  "Enable ARC" flag for that static library/target if your version of Xcode adds it by default 3) build and link your app to the static library. 4) done. there are many step-by-steps for configuring static libs out there.

Answer (score 1):

You can select multiple files in the Compile Sources list and apply the `-fno-objc-arc` tag to all of them at once by pressing Enter > Paste > Enter.

Comment: True, though if any flags were preexisting they would be overwritten.  This works great though if they are all the same.